# Prevent clear history ion tabs navigation

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I'm developing an app based on ion-tabs. I want to freely use$ionicHistory.goBack() , but at the moment if I go to another tab I have $ionicHistory cleared (reference to previous view is undefined).

Is there a way to disable history clear on each tab change? I need something that also maintain android back button working correctly.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `$state.go()` instead of `$ionicHistory.goBack()`. `$ionicHistory.goBack()` pops the current state from state stack while `$state.go()` keeps the current state and pushes the new one